# Query without duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have created three tables. One is `MidTerm`, the other is `FinalTerm` and the last one is `Results`.

Each of them have as columns: Student_ID, Student_Name, Score, Course_ID.

It means there are the same students in all tables with same ID but with different scores. I wanna retrieve, query  Student_ID, Student_Name and Scores  from all of three tables. But when I do so there are a lot of duplicates. One Student can have one ID but many courses so many course ID which means he can have more than one score.

How do I write a query for it?

```
SELECT dbo.FinalTerm.Student_ID, dbo.FinalTerm.Student_Name, dbo.FinalTerm.Score, dbo.Results.Score AS Expr1, dbo.Results.Course_ID, 
                      dbo.MidTerm.Score AS Expr2, dbo.MidTerm.Course_ID AS Expr3, dbo.FinalTerm.Course_ID AS Expr4
FROM         dbo.FinalTerm INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Results ON dbo.FinalTerm.ID = dbo.Results.ID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.MidTerm ON dbo.Results.Student_ID = dbo.MidTerm.Student_ID
```

Comment: Hey, we are not here to solve your problems if you apparently don't even try yourself. Please let us know what you tried, and what is not working; then maybe someone will look at it.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what you're trying to do. Could you supply some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it please?

Comment: @Skofiar  I suggest you make one table for 'MidTerm' and 'FinalTerm' and just set a bit or tiny int to identify which is which. Also what is 'Results' as in the final result of the 2 together. There isn't enough information provided in your question. Also Distinct goes along way

Comment: You have tagged your question "mysql" and  yet "dbo" is almost always associated with SQL Server.  What database are you really using?

Comment: Impossible to answer without an example of your desired results.   saying you want all the results without duplicates is self-contradictory.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use GROUP_CONCAT if your intention was to list all scores for a student

```
SELECT 
    m.Student_ID, m.Student_Name, GROUP_CONCAT(m.Score,' ',f.Score,' ',r.Score)
FROM 
    MidTerm m
    inner join FinalTerm f on m.Student_ID = f.Student_ID
    inner join Results r on f.Student_ID = r.Student_ID
GROUP BY 
    Student_ID, Student_Name;
```

Also you probably shouldn't keep student_name in all the tables. A better way would be to create a student table where you would keep all student details and just leave student_id in other tables to reference the student table

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is not 100% clear, but just my guess of what you are looking for:

```
SELECT
dbo.FinalTerm.Student_ID, 
dbo.FinalTerm.Student_Name, 
dbo.FinalTerm.Course_ID,
SUM(dbo.FinalTerm.Score) as FinalScore, 
SUM(dbo.Results.Score) AS ResultsScore, 
SUM(dbo.MidTerm.Score) AS MidTermScore
FROM
  dbo.FinalTerm 
LEFT JOIN dbo.Results 
ON dbo.FinalTerm.Student_ID = dbo.Results.Student_ID
  AND  dbo.FinalTerm.Course_ID = dbo.Results.Course_ID
LEFT JOIN dbo.MidTerm 
ON dbo.FinalTerm.Student_ID = dbo.MidTerm.Student_ID
  AND dbo.FinalTerm.Course_ID = dbo.MidTerm.Course_ID
GROUP BY dbo.FinalTerm.Student_ID, dbo.FinalTerm.Course_ID
```